# Force HTTPS with rewrite rule

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I want to force HTTP to HTTPS redirection. I tried the following :

```
<VirtualHost *:1882>
    ServerAdmin ***
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    ServerAlias ApplicationServer
    ProxyRequests Off

  #Force SSL
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 1882
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

  #Certificats SSL
  SSLEngine on
  SSLVerifyClient none
  SSLCertificateFile "D:/ssl/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/ssl/server.key"

  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/none"

    ErrorLog "${INSTALL_DIR}/logs/app_error.log"
  CustomLog "${INSTALL_DIR}/logs/app_access.log" combined

    <Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

But while testing, HTTPS work, but HTTP return error 400.
I checked my condition [HERE](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) and it seems to be good.

Do my rewrite rule need to be written elsewhere ?

## EDIT :

Fixed by adding this virtualhost :

```
<VirtualHost *:1884>
  #Force SSL
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 1884
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule (.*) https://<URL_TO_HTTPS_VIRTUALHOSTL>%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is incomplete because you need 2 different Virtual Hosts : one for handling plain text traffic (HTTP), another for the HTTPS. What we see is a mix of the two.. in this virtual host we understand it is supposed to catch non SSL traffic but at the same time you're giving SSL directives which lead to schizophrenia and 400 error.

Comment: So basically, i have to create a new Virtualhost with only this rewrite rule ? Like Virtualhost *:1884 with the "#Force SSL" section ?

Comment: Yes, and it seems to work from what you said in the EDIT.